# 5 Dataframes in one plot using Pandas & Matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have 5 dataframes and they have same structures. I want to plot them in one plot for comparison. I have tried with the following code:

```
path1 =  C:\\Users\\amit.tyagi\\Desktop\\dumps2\\tweet_counts\\bayesian_count.csv'
path2 = 'C:\\Users\\amit.tyagi\\Desktop\\dumps2\\tweet_counts\\fixed_count.csv'
path3 = 'C:\\Users\\amit.tyagi\\Desktop\\dumps2\\tweet_counts\\skwa_count.csv'
path4 = 'C:\\Users\\amit.tyagi\\Desktop\\dumps2\\tweet_counts\\rkwa_count.csv'
path5 = 'C:\\Users\\amit.tyagi\\Desktop\\dumps2\\tweet_counts\\cetre_count.csv'


data1 = pd.read_csv(path1, names=['timestamp', 'count_bayes'])
data2 = pd.read_csv(path2, names=['timestamp', 'count_fixed'])
data3 = pd.read_csv(path3, names=['timestamp', 'count_skwa'])
data4 = pd.read_csv(path4, names=['timestamp', 'count_rkwa'])
data5 = pd.read_csv(path5, names=['timestamp', 'count_cetre'])

df12 = pd.merge(data1, data2, how='outer', on='timestamp')
df123 = pd.merge(df12, data3, how='outer', on='timestamp')
df1234 = pd.merge(df123, data4, how='outer', on='timestamp')
df12345 = pd.merge(df1234, data5, how='outer', on='timestamp')

df12345.plot()
```

And I get the following plot:

[image: plot]

But this is not what I actually want. It created 5 windows and plotted them separately. I want them all on same axis i.e X-Axis (timestamps). Can someone help to figure out the mistake am I making?

[Sample data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6kQrczTEsgncnJBdHdPbmFlV1U)

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your plot shows the five in one figure, no? Do you mean that you want the horizontal axis to be the timestamp?

Comment: Yes, Exactly. I want horizontal axis to be the timestamps and Y-axis to be the count for each data frame.

Comment: It would greatly help if you could give us a sample of your data, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi I have added a link to sample data files to google drive.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution by myself. Thanks for helping me.

[image: Here is the plot]